# iOS - Storing multiple values in one variable

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating 5 integer variables to store 5 different values in Objective C. For ex: intA, intB etc

Below is just sample code:

For example:

```
for (Desframe *obj in [myval allValues])
{
    if (obj.A>10.0) {
        myLabel.text = @"A";
        intA = intA++;
    }
    else if (obj.B>10.0) {
        myLabel1.text = @"B";
        intB = intB++;
    }
    else if (obj.C>10.0) {
        myLabe2.text = @"C";
        intC = intC++;
    }
    else if (obj.D>10.0) {
        myLabe3.text = @"D";
        intD = intD++;
    }
    else if (obj.E>10.0) {
        myLabe4.text = @"E";
        intE = intE++;
    }    
}
```

In future, I may need to add 2 more variables.
I would like to know how to avoid creating 5 different integer variables but have 5 different values stored in one variable. Should I use array?
(or) how to handle this code professionally?

But I want this variable to be accessed globally in the same class (.m) file.

Kindly share your suggestion and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use an `NSMutableArray` for this. However, Objective-C `NSArray`s are a little strange since they can only contain objects. You'll have to "box" the entries as NSNumber objects:

```
NSMutableArray *numbers = @[@(1), @(2), @(3), @(4), @(5)];
```

And then you can fetch an item from the array:

```
NSNumber *aNumber = numbers[0];
```

But NSNumber Objects are immutable.

You might want to use a C-style array:

```
UInt64 numbers[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Then you could say

```
numbers[0]++;
```

But with a statically allocated C-style array you can't add elements to the array at runtime.

Comment: Swift cleans up all this weirdness. You can simply create a var array of ints: `var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and append numbers to it, increment values inside the array, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NSMutableDictionary` with keys being your `A` - `E` here and integers as values.

That way, for instance, to add values (5 now and potentially more in the future) you would write:

`[dict setObject:@123 forKey:@"A"];`

To retrieve them:

`[dict objectForKey:@"A"];`

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own struct.

```
struct MyStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
}
```

And use this new type in your class

```
@implementation MyClass {
    MyStruct example;

    // In your function
        for (Desframe *obj in [myval allValues])
        {
            if (obj.A>10.0) {
                myLabel.text = @"A";
                example.a += 1;
            }
                else if (obj.B>10.0) {
                myLabel1.text = @"B";
                example.b += 1;
            }

            // And so on ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Objective-C, not Swift

Comment: Thanks. Corrected.